# ggplot2 : Multiple years on Same Plot by Month & assigning variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, time-series, timeserieschart

I have a quick question about plotting variables for
multiple years as shown on this link:
[ggplot: Multiple years on same plot by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206181/ggplot-multiple-years-on-same-plot-by-month)
How do I assign my variable where "value" is located instead of fake data?

## Access data at this link

### library(readr)

```
rawdata <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dewittpe/f9942bce11c34edabf888cbf8375ff17/raw/cb2b527fb2ee5c9c288b3246359c57d36df9fc6e/Data.csv")
```

## 0. SETUP DATA

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
value <- rawdata$Value #Name of variable from csv

dat1 = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1995-01-01"),
as.Date("1995-12-01"), "1 month"),
              value = cumsum(rnorm(12)))  ###How do I assign my variable where "value" is located instead of fake data?
dat1$date = as.yearmon(dat1$date)  

dat2 = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1996-01-01"),
as.Date("1996-12-01"), "1 month"),
              value = cumsum(rnorm(12)))
dat2$date = as.yearmon(dat2$date)


ggplot(rbind(dat1,dat2), aes(month(date, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE), 
                         value, group=factor(year(date)),
                         colour=factor(year(date)))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Month", colour="Year") +
  theme_classic()'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RibTl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion: use [`readr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readr) to read the data into R.  This will help with setting the storage modes for each column.   I made a copy of the data set in a github gist.  To read the data into R use

```
library(readr)

dat1 <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dewittpe/f9942bce11c34edabf888cbf8375ff17/raw/cb2b527fb2ee5c9c288b3246359c57d36df9fc6e/Data.csv")
```

Once the data has been read in, the graphic is generated as follows.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Use dplyr::filter to filter the data to the years of interest.

dat1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(lubridate::year(date) %in% 1995:1996) %>%

ggplot(.) +
  aes(x = lubridate::month(date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE),
      y = value,
      group = factor(lubridate::year(date)),
      color = factor(lubridate::year(date))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Month", color = "Year") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter, would it be possible to select which years I'd want to plot and by month as i had it using your method? Run my code for illustration. Thank you.

Comment: Use `dplyr::filter` to filter the data set.  I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for time!

Comment: Quick question, how would i be able to select   dplyr::filter(lubridate::year(date) %in% 1995:1997) %>% and add 2002 excluding 1998-2001? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, use `dat1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(lubridate::year(date) %in% c(1995, 1996, 2002))`

Comment: I get error "Error in ggplot(.) : object '.' not found", I tried to wrap ggplot around the aes but got error "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval"

Comment: Last question, is there to change the ordering of the months? ie start with November and end with October or should i ask another question? Thanks again

Comment: Did you have the `%>%` to pipe the data into `ggplot`?  `dat1 %>% dplyr::filter(ubridate::year(date) %in% c(1995, 1996, 2002)) %>% ggplot(.) + aes(....`

Comment: It worked! Thank you, Peter. I forgot to add the %>%.